# incorrect Read MSSQL DateTime from java

Tags: java, sql-server

I noticed to an error as bellow.
There is a table in mssql with datetime field. In java app, I tried to get given info as bellow.

```
sqlCmd = "select top 5 convert(Date,creation_date) xdate from outbound_messages";
s.executeQuery(sqlCmd);
rs = s.getResultSet();
while (rs.next()) {
     String xdate = rs.getDate("xdate").toString()
}
```

If I run under jdk 1.7.0_03 I will get incorrect date (2 days before) but works well under v6 !!!
I am using "sqljdbc4.jar" as sql lib.
If sql statement changed to c"convert(char(10),creation_date,121)" works well.
Any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You may store a timestamp `date.getTime()` in your database as a long and parse it into Date object when you retrieve data from your database, I think this could fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks Romain, but incorrect,Field contains full date and time and when I get it as given source, it returns date as two days before!!